# Regular expressions to replace

Tags: regex, notepad++, textpad

I need to replace a bunch of lines for SQL queries

The format is like

> "xyzabcd >  hdsd + 5 and",
>   "xzbcd_TTM_dfdfd >  hdsd + 20 and",
>   "x_TTM_dfsddsdsdfd >  hdsd + 20 and"

I need to find the keyword TTM and add a "(" at the beginning and " or some condition)" in the end but before the word "and"

So the line

> "xzbcd_TTM_dfdfd >  hdsd + 20 and",

becomes

> "(xzbcd_TTM_dfdfd >  hdsd + 20 or some condition) and

I am trying to do it in Textpad but I can also use Notepad++. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `([a-zA-Z]+_TTM_[a-zA-Z]+\s+>hdsd\s+\d+)\s+and` with something like `(\1 OR some condition) and` (don't know the group placeholders in Notepad++). Best to use case-insensitive matching.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. seem I am missing something basic. As mentioned below, I tried to replace C_TTM_xxx with just to add opening parenthesis right now and replaced ._TTM with \(\1 but it replaced whole string with it. So C_TTM_xxx became (_xxx instead of becoming (C_TTM_xxx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Notepad++ and for TextPad you can use

Search:

```
"(.+)\sand",*
```

Replace:

```
"\(\1 OR some condition\) AND
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. for example I tried to replace C_TTM_xxx with just to add opening parenthesis right now and replaced ._TTM with \(\1 but it replaced whole string with it. So C_TTM_xxx became (_xxx instead of becoming (C_TTM_xxx

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you give a full example. For now I'm not sure if you have a `"` at beginning or not.

Comment: Nopes I don't have it. For starters, I just tried to change C_TTM_xxx to (C_TTM_xxx. but I was not able to. can you tell me how to do that. I will do the next part after I find out how to do this.

Comment: Search `(.*)` Replace `\(\1` will replace `C_TTM_xxx` to `(C_TTM_xxx`

Comment: Great. This worked. Thank You. There are lines without the keyword TTM too. So I replaced (._TTM*) with \(\1. Now how do I replace (C_TTM_xxx and to (C_TTM_xxx yyy and.

Comment: This has got a good answer. Thank you for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817020/search-and-replace-in-textpad-notepadd-using-regex