# Search and Replace in textpad/notepadd++ using RegEx

Tags: regex, notepad++, textpad

I need to do search and replace in textpad or notepad++. So I am trying to use Regular Expressions. I have some lines like below

```
(C_ABCD_ehfjdhf dj hfdjhfhj and
(S_dfdfdddff 20 and
(P_ABCD_fmngfngm gfnm and
```

I need to check for the key word ABCD and if found , add a constant value before the last word. In result I want above lines to be as follows

```
(C_ABCD_ehfjdhf dj hfdjhfhj CONSTANT and
(S_dfdfdddff 20 and
(P_ABCD_fmngfngm gfnm CONSTANT and
```

Since first and third line had the keyword ABCD, the term CONSTANT needs to be added before ending word

I had raised a similar question before but I think I was not able to explain the problem correctly. Here is the link for that

[Regular expressions to replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814461/regular-expressions-to-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
(ABCD[\w\s]+)( [a-zA-Z]+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF2pO5/2)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a peach. I would have otherwise need to sift through 1200 lines and make changes to 360 of them. Much obliged...

Comment: Note that this is only as good as the problem definition in your example. The character class in group 1 will only capture spaces `[\r\n\t\f ]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` You may have lines that have scented letters (`è` for example, symbols, etc, etc). You may want to use `ABCD[\w ]+` so that `\n` is not included.